# CTRL + Click not working

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2007

Code browsing is not working for my project. I set the Search Path to all the Source units that I am using. And also I deleted the `.local` and `.identcache` files. My project is compiling with no problems. What can I do to make `ctrl + click` work.

Thanks

Comment: David H.'s answer is correct, but you should understand it generally. There is some bit of complicated syntax in one of your units that is not supported. Most of us just learn to live without Ctrl+Click, because it's not easily possible to get it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One bug that I am aware of occurs when you have a class which declares a record inline, as so:

```
TMyClass = class
private
  FData: record
    MyData: Integer;
  end;
end;
```

If you have any code like this then many of the IDE's code insight/completion/whatever features stop working. This fault stretches right back to Delphi 6 and possibly beyond.

I fix it with an class private type declaration:

```
TMyClass = class
private
  type 
    TData = record
      MyData: Integer;
    end;
private
  FData: TData;
end;
```

But if that syntax is not available in D2007 then you'd need to declare the record type outside the class.

Another factor which I find can confuse the IDE is if you are using a lot of conditional statements (`$IFDEF` and the like).

Finally I'd recommend installing Andreas Hausladen's [IDEFixPack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/) which does improve IDE behaviour.

Of course, your problem may be caused by something else, but without being able to experiment with your actual code, we have to guess to a degree.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i am not having such declarations in my code

Comment: It's likely to be some aspect of your code that confuses the IDE. Try deleting portions of it, removing units until you isolate some piece of code that triggers the behaviour.

Comment: Yeah currently I am doing that and thanks again for the suggestion

Comment: +1. Note that there are a great many syntax cases that the error-insight parser silently fails to handle.  Just because the OP doesn't have this one, doesn't mean there isn't another.  Also, reusing a common identifier name, class name, seems to bring this on.

Comment: @Warren Thanks. You're quite right, anything a bit too funky freaks the IDE out. It's just that this is the one I was dealing with today so it was at the front of my mind!!

Comment: Don't you wish there was a better way than randomly removing bits of your app? :-)

Comment: @Warren Well, yes that would be nice. On the other hand, have you used Visual Studio 2010? It's AV city, crashes all the time just like Delphi 4 used to!

Comment: The sub type syntax is available in Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl-Click easily gets confused when you use conditional defines to control what code gets compiled:

```
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
...
{$ENDIF}
```

Usually it needs a couple of these, but sometimes a single one of these, especially in the interface section, is enough to send Ctrl-Click into confusion.

Another time when I have seen Ctrl-Click not to work is when you are using project groups and the unit you have in the editor does not belong to the project that is currently active in the project group.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with code browsing in my module (in Delphi XE3). Look for your source code and find construction like this:

```
procedure procName;
begin
  if ... then
  begin
     ...
  end else
end;
```

Attention to last "else".
The compiler understands this code, but Code Browsing don't.
It's need to insert ";" after "else" or erase "else". 
After this correction of source, the Code Browser is working.